# How come when I push "up" on MongoDB's console, it doesn't cycle through my previous command?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

Instead, it displays this:

^[[A^[[A

Answer (score 1):

update to mongo 1.6+
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

(via http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/8611c444fdfe2fe0?pli=1)

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you post this question on MongoDb's mailing list with little more explanation that after which command you face this problem because this is not the normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that may be of some use, though I have not yet gotten it to work:

http://www.mongodbadmin.com/node/149

This seems to assume you are installing mongo from source.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have `readline` installed, so the mongo shell falls back to a simple mode without history navigation using the arrow keys.